# ASM inline assembly bubble sort; constant value required, garbage at end of line

Tags: c, assembly, avr, inline-assembly, avr-gcc

I have an Arduino MEGA program written in C that populates an array with random integers, then calls a bubble sort algorithm written in ASM inline assembly. The sorted integers are then converted into binary and eight LEDs are lit with each LED corresponding to one bit of the binary number.

Firstly, the declared global variables.

```
const byte arraySize = 10;
volatile byte randomNums[arraySize]; 
volatile byte limit = arraySize-1;
volatile byte counter = 1;
volatile byte iteration = 1;
```

Next, the main program loop (for simplicity, I will omit the binary conversion and LED code).

```
void loop() {

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        randomNums[i] = random(255);
    }

    // asm inline bubble sort here
}
```

Lastly, the bubble sort algorithm in ASM inline assembly.

```
asm volatile(

    "               lds        r20, (limit)        ; position before end of array \n"
    "               lds        r21, (counter)      ; counter for loop is defined i=0 \n"
    "               lds        r22, (iteration)    ; counter set for iteration of sort algorithm k=1 \n"
    "               mov        r21, r27            ; i=1 \n"
    "               mov        r22, r28            ; iteration number in r28=k \n"
    "               lds        r23, (randomNums)   ; point to beginning of array by r23 'element' \n"
    "               mov        r23, r24            "
    "               add        1, r24              ; point to 'neighbour' \n"
    
    " check%=:      mov        r23, r25            ; get 'element' and place in r25 \n"
    "               mov        r24, r26            ; get 'neighbour' in array in r26 \n"
    "               cp         r25, r26            ; compare both values \n"
    "               brge       swap%=              ; swap the numbers \n"
    "               add        1, r23              ; increment pointer r23 \n"
    "               add        1, r24              ; increment pointer r24 \n"
    "               add        1, r27              ; increment loop counter \n"
    "               eor        r27, (limit)        ; xor check if not exceeding array size \n"
    "               brne       check%=             "
    
    " swap%=:       mov        r23, r24            ; swap content where index r23 is pointing to where index r24 is pointing \n"
    "               mov        r26, r23            ; move greater number to position after smaller number \n"
    "               add        1, r23              ; increment pointer r23 \n"
    "               add        1, r24              ; increment pointer r24 \n"
    "               add        1, r28              ; increment loop counter \n"
    "               cp         r28, (arraySize)    ; check not exceeding array capacity \n"
    "               ret                            "         
                              
    ::: "r20", "r21", "r22", "r23", "r24", "r25", "r26", "r27", "r28"); // clobbered registers
```

The program works (save for the sorting) when the assembly is commented out. When I compile the program with the assembly, I get the following obscure errors.

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2d2uAp.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2d2uAp.s:1963: Error: garbage at end of line
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2d2uAp.s:1971: Error: constant value required
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2d2uAp.s:1972: Error: garbage at end of line
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2d2uAp.s:1977: Error: constant value required
lto-wrapper.exe: fatal error: E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
e:/program files (x86)/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Mega ADK.
```

I've searched online and taken a look at the AVR assembly manual and I can't figure out what these errors mean and where they are occurring. I'll add that I'm new to AVR assembly and ASM inline.

Comment: Why do you write inline assembly instead of writing an ordinary assembly file?

Comment: start with real assembly then if absolutely necessary, port that to inline assembly.

Comment: Just out of interest, what happens when you put `\n` at the end of *every* string component? There are three missing (the lines without comments).

Comment: @paxdiablo I didn't notice that! that fixed the 'garbage at end of line' errors. however, the other two remain

Comment: @fuz most of the program is already written in C, but I wanted to try my hand at assembly after I discovered AVR could be used with Arduino

Comment: @old_timer is there a particular reason why?

Comment: You should ask your compiler to keep the assembly temporary file so you can cross reference the line numbers. Anyway, your problems are likely the `add 1, r24`, `eor r27, (limit)` and `cp r28, (arraySize)`. If you consult a manual you will see none of those instructions take immediate or memory operands. Registers only.

Comment: See also [Reasons you should NOT use inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm)

Comment: @Jester changed the xor and compare ops to use registers and it compiled correctly. Thanks for sharing that too, I will give it a read.

Comment: @Jester, are you sure on the `add 1, r24`? That instruction type occurs *seven* times so I'd expect a lot more errors.

Comment: Good catch. It actually assembles as `add r1, r24` which is still not what Zac wants of course.

Comment: @Zac inline assembly is its own beast, all assembly languages are tool specific not target there are many avr assembly languages for example, mostly the same.  But then when you add compiler specific (not C language standard) inline around it you create more problems.  Why make life hard if you are trying to learn or use asm.  walk before you run.  crawl before you walk.

Comment: If you are trying for a full function or a decent size chunk of code just do the whole function in assembly language, inline doesnt buy you anything.  start with C to implement the code. Compile that. Then take that assembly language then hand tune if possible or re-write as needed.  Increase your odds of success.

Comment: @old_timer I see. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: @Zac That's fine and well, but if you are writing whole functions in assembly, it's generally a lot easier to just make a new assembly file and write your function in there.  You can then link this file into your project and use it in conjunction with a project otherwise written in C.  The GNU C Compiler's inline assembly is notoriously tricky to use correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "garbage at end of line" problems are caused by missing `\n` characters at the end of the lines. There are three of these lines but I suspect the third is okay because it's at the end.

The other two problems are with the following lines, I don't believe these are allowed to have memory operands:

```
eor r27, (limit)
cp  r28, (arraySize)
```

The line number differences between those two lines match the difference (`1977 - 1971`) in the generated errors, once you take into account the following two lines are considered as *one* due to the missing `\n` on the first:

```
"               brne       check%=   "
" swap%=:       mov        r23, r24  ; swap content ... \n'
```

---

As an aside (as pointed out by Jester in the comments), it looks like Atmel don't *have* an immediate-operand `ADD` instruction (see [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf)), so I'd be circumspect about instructions of the form:

```
add 1, r27
```

There are a number of possibilities why this might be allowed:

- The problem could just be hidden by your current errors;
- It could be a deficiency in the inline assembler that treats it as `add r1, r27`;
- It could be a *feature* in the inline assembler in that it could be generating code to *emulate* this operation.

On that last point, I've seen this sort of thing done before, such as a "multi-register push":

```
push r1, r7, r42
```

which just assembles to three single-register pushes.

It *may* be that the assembler is smart enough to turn `add 1, r27` into `inc r27`. Since the only immediate value you're adding is `1`, this is a possibility.

This also points to a possible solution should it turn out to be a deficiency and it's erroneously adding `r1` rather than `1`, to `r27`. Just turn those `add` instructions into `inc` instructions.

---

And just commenting on your code *logic* rather than just the syntax, I'm not sure you've correctly separated the pointer and content concepts correctly. It looks like `r23/24` are meant to be the *addresses* of cells in the `randomNums` array but the instruction:

```
lds r23, (randomNums)
```

will load the first *value* of that array into the register. So, consider:

```
                    +---+---+---+---+
randomNums @ 0x1000 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
                    +---+---+---+---+
```

The instruction  you use would have `r23` being the value `4` rather than he address `1000`. The `ldi` instruction is what you would use to load up an immediate value.

---

Even after fixing that, extracting the values using:

```
mov r23, r25
mov r24, r26
```

won't work because you're transferring the *addresses,* not using those addresses to get the *values* for comparison.

Loading values indirectly using a register is usually done by loading that register into one that can be used by the `lpm` instruction, such as `Z` (`R30/31`).

---

Additionally, while you *branch* to `swap`, you *return* from there meaning, even if you had the right addresses set up, you would swap at most one pair of elements.

One fix is to *call* `swap` as a subroutine, rather than branching to it, and modify it so that it *only* swaps and returns, removing the register manipulations and comparison - they should be done back in the main code.

The other (preferable in my opinion) is to treat it like an `if` statement and just skip over the code that swaps, something like:

```
           cp    r25, r26      ; compare both values.
           brle  noswap%=      ; skip swap if already ordered.

           @swap (r25), (r26)  ; actual code to swap goes here.
noswap%=:
           add        1, r23   ; carry on with loop.
```

Comment: The `add 1, r27` is a feature of the actual assembler (`gas`). It will treat the number as a register number, so anything from 0 to 31 goes: _"register name or number from 0 to 31 required"_. It will not emit an `inc`. It produces `1b 0e add r1, r27`

Comment: Though all the compiler errors were fixed, even after changing the `add` opcode to `inc` opcodes, the program still does not work for some unknown reason. Nothing seems to be broken, no errors are thrown, it just doesn't work. Looks like asm inline isn't the best way to try assembly after all. Thank you for your answer, though!

Comment: @Zac: Correct, GNU C inline asm is the worst way to learn asm.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm.  You have to already know exactly what your asm does and be able to describe it accurately to the compiler with input/output/clobber constraints, otherwise you'll step on its toes. (Or at least use a `"memory"` clobber along with your `asm volatile`; [How can I indicate that the memory *pointed* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56432259)). Write a whole function in asm (respecting the calling convention), and call it from C with args and get a return value.

Comment: @Zac, I've added a few notes on your code logic that should hopefully help you out on that point.

Comment: @pax: I'd recommend against over-complicating Bubble Sort by making `swap` a function.  You already have a pointer and 2 values in registers, just branch over two store instructions (that use opposite source regs to how you loaded).  The whole point of BubbleSort is that it's very simple in asm (https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/papers/bubble.pdf).  If you're keeping the previous `array[i]` in a register instead of doing 2 loads per iterations, you'd also need a `mov` reg,reg along after the stores to get the right value in the right register for next iteration.